# RegEx to find and replace a pattern in SublimeText

Tags: regex

I need to use a Regular Expression in SublimeText for a Find and Replace search.

My search string pattern looks like this:

```
chrome.i18n.getMessage("nimbusBtnLogin")
```

in which case I need to replace with:

```
"nimbusBtnLogin"
```

---

I have a GIST here https://gist.github.com/jasondavis/fda85e808a6c8184adad where I have listed the RegEx for a find and replace of HTML form selection option fields, links, and images however I was unable to modify and get working for this pattern above.

Can someone please share the correct RegEx?

Comment: Perhaps, just `\b\w+(?:\.\w+)*\("(.*?)"\)` --> `$1`?

Comment: Or [`[^(]+\(([^)]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/wQ6uE8/1) --> `$1`.

Comment: This is not very well constrained... The way the question is posed, it could just be `(".+")` What are all the variations of the `...getMessage` portion that you expect?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works however it also replaces other strings like this for example `css("overflow", "auto")`

Comment: Sure, then `\b\w+(?:\.\w+)*\("([^"]*)"\)`. I guess there can be more "but"s, right? Please formulate the requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My goal is to only replace strings that contain `chrome.i18n.getMessage("TEXT-STRING")` => `"TEXT-STRING"`

Comment: Then `\bchrome\.i18n\.getMessage\("([^"]*)"\)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect thanks.  Would you like to post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\bchrome\.i18n\.getMessage\("([^"]*)"\)
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR8xX8/1)

Note:

- `\bchrome\.i18n\.getMessage\("` - matches literal string (matched as a whole word) `chrome.i18n.getMessage("` (special characters are escaped since they must be treated as literals)
- `([^"]*)` - matches and captures into Group 1 any characters other than `"`
- `"\)` - matches literal `")`